Reduce quadratic form to canonical form using linear transformation.
I have to reduce the quadratic form
$f = 4xz - 3yz$
using theorem: for any quadratic form, there exists a non-degenerate linear transformation by means of which this form can be reduced to the canonical form.
I substituted
$- x = z_1 - z_2
- y = z_1 + z_2
- z = z_3$
but the equation becomes
$z_1 z_2 - 7 z_2 z_3$
How can I linearly transform it into canonical form if I get only cross-terms?
Do I substitute $z_1, z_2, z_3$ with different equations or is the form $0Y_1^2 + 0Y_2^2 + 0Y_3^2$?
